# codename one how to place component on an image viewer that capture camera?

Tags: camera, cross-platform, codenameone

I have a GUI Builder created form in codename one, how can i open the camera in a resizable view at the show() of the form and place container like text area or anything else on it?
I saw the camera demo but i don't understand it very well because on the simulator it open a file picker.
My purpose is to create a form with a camera resizable capture when you have two labels and you can also write or paint on your photo used in background, I do this only for hobby and fun, i do what i can, Any advice is well accepted, thank you for the attenction

Answer (score 0):

You can now place a component on top of a camera view with a new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

Original answer below:

I'm assuming you mean overlay on a live camera view. While this is possible it's not supported at this time in the Java API layer.

If you mean grabbing a photo and setting it as a background for the form for overlay you can create an image with the result of the `Capture` API and use setBgImage() to set that image to the background of a component or form.

Comment: Hi, first thank you for the attention, i' ve read that the "aumented reality" isn't possible for now in codename so i would opt for a form in wich you can take a picture and, after taking it, use it for background like you advice me and add some components on them like text area label or anything else, i haven't yet understood if i create the form with the gui builder how and where I have to write the code for setting the image in background , in general, i haven't understood how can i "get" the components created with the gui form builder and work with them in the code.

Comment: for example: put the camera capture in a image viewer in the form and then use this image in background and put other components over them or i don't know, change the text of a label or change the icon of a button created with the gui builder, I tried to be as clear as possible and hope it. thank you very much again.

Comment: You can change the text of a button using the text properties on the side. You can change a forms background image by using `form.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage()`. You would want to style the form to use scaled to fill style see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html

Comment: I mean via code not via gui builder, i want to change the icon of a button when the user want to change it (like a profile picture) , I don't understand where and how can i get a gui component in the java code and work with it. for ex: I have 6 buttons where i would to show my favourite 6 contacts dinamically according to how much i chat with them, the button icon have to change every day or every week if my preferences changes, thank you again, you really help me

Comment: If you are using the new GUI builder your form is a subclass. If you are not then you **should** but in that old one you can find the parent form of a component thru `getComponentForm()`.